# Is there a way to assign “Align to Selection”, “Align to Artboard”, etc to a keys or to one key so I can toggle between them?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

[image: Illustrator screenshot]

You can’t do it with keyboard shortcuts as it is not a menu item.

I want to this as I have assigned the other align commands to my WACOM buttons:

I made a complex keyboard shortcut for each of the commands in Illustrator (so I don’t press it accidentally). Then using the WACOM sys pref pane I then just assigned that complex button press to the key that I want. Using different combinations of modifiers I can assign all the keys and select different things using SHIFT.

But I can’t do this with the highlighted items as they don’t appear in the Keyboard Shortcuts menu. I don’t like having to open up that little tag every time I want to change the mode.

Answer (score 1):

Key objects are designated by an extra click.

Select a bunch of object, then click one more time on the object you want as the key object. The key object will get a thicker highlight on it. This sets *that* object as the key. There's no need to use the panels. Then align.

[image]

There is no way to have a button implement the key object (or any align function) because Illustrator needs to know *which* object you are referring to. It would be nice to be able to toggle those options with a button, shortcut or single click, but it's currently not possible.

The Only way I think you could implement what you are referring to is via actions that are set specifically to use the artboard or selection.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not a tool or a menu this is not possible (at the moment). It is however possible to request this feature [here](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform&loc=en).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only by specific App. For me it is BetterTouchTool

[image]